# my asp.net web service code is giving error

Tags: asp.net

hello i have created the code for extracting age from table test 
but instead of returning the age it is returning me the following statement

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

here is the code

[WebMethod]

```
    public string Getcustomername(string name)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GURJOT;Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();

        com.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        com.CommandText = "SELECT * from test WHERE Name='" + name + "'";
        SqlDataReader dt = com.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Read();
        con.Close();
        dt.Close();
        return dt.ToString();
```

any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning `dt.ToString()` you should return the value of a field:

```
public string GetCustomerAge(string name)
{
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GURJOT;Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security=True"))
  {
    using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
    { 
      com.Connection = con;
      con.Open();
      com.CommandText = "SELECT age from test WHERE Name='" + name + "'";
      using (SqlDataReader dt = com.ExecuteReader())
      {
        if (dt.Read())
        {
          return System.Convert.ToString(dt.GetValue(0));
        }
      }
  }
  return "";
}
```

And please, use parameterized queries - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection .